# Memory Limit in Spark/kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

Is there any way to set limit of number of records while consuming data from Kafka.
i.e. I have 1000 Records in Kafka, after consuming events from Kafka, Placing at HDFS location. I  am trying to add the configuration(by spark  submit command) so at a time it can only read and process 100 records instead of consuming all the 1000 records, so this way it will consume less memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` to limit the number of records to fetch

To limit total memory, though, can either force the Spark executors to have a fixed heap size, and you can try passing `kafka.max.poll.records` config option to the readStream options to be more explicit to the consumer for limiting polled records.

---

You could alternatively use Kafka Connect HDFS Sink, which has a `flush.size` parameter for records per file.

Note that HDFS prefers larger files, and not lots of tiny ones

Comment: I tried setting 'max.poll.records=100'  In consumer Config still when I am cheking the job logs its showing  "numInputRows" : 1000. @OneCricketeer

Comment: In the logs, you should see `ConsumerConfig` section. Make sure that `max.poll.records` in the output there matches what you set. it's also possible Spark polls multiple times (once per executor), then returns you all of them as your Dataset; so, for example, 10 executors can read 10 topic partitions, polling 100 records, resulting in 1000 records overall. In any case, Kafka records have a default limit of 1MB, so 1000 records would only be 1GB, which is smaller than most Spark executor heap sizes that I personally have worked with.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. It worked with maxOffsetPerTrigger property.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this